# nginx 414 HTTP ERROR, 301 redirect broke my website

Tags: nginx

I wanted to do a 301 redirect form www.kasacja-aut.pl to kasacja-aut.pl and then something strange hapend.

Now my website is redirecting to itself like this:
https://kasacja-aut.pl/kasacja-aut.pl/kasacja-aut.pl/kasacja-aut.pl/kasacja-aut.pl/kasacja-aut.pl/... and over again!

```
server {
listen 80;
listen [::]:80;
server_name  www.kasacja-aut.pl kasacja-aut.pl;
return 301 https://$kasacja-aut.pl$request_uri;


server {
listen 443 ssl http2;
server_name          kasacja-aut.pl;
index index.html bialogard.html gdansk.html goleniow.html karlino.html kolobrzeg.html koszalin.html miedzyzdroje.html police.html stargard.html swinoujscie.html
szczecin.html szczecinek.html;
root   /var/www/kasacja-aut.pl;


sendfile       off;

access_log /var/log/nginx/auto-kasacja.pl/access.log;
error_log  /var/log/nginx/auto-kasacja.pl/error.log;

    client_body_timeout 5s;
    client_header_timeout 5s;

#Bezpieczeństwo
    add_header Strict-Transport-Security max-age=15768000;

    #Zabezpiecz ciastka :]
    proxy_cookie_domain ~(?P<secure_domain>([-0-9a-z]+\.)?[-0-9a-z]+\.[a-z]+)$ "$secure_domain; secure";

    # Clickjacking security.
    add_header                      X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN;
        add_header                      X-Content-Type-Options nosniff;
        add_header                      X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";

ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/auto-kasacja.pl/key.key;
ssl_certificate     /etc/ssl/auto-kasacja.pl/cloudflare.crt;
ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;


ssl_session_cache   shared:SSL:30m;
ssl_session_timeout 30m;

keepalive_timeout   70;

# CLOUDFLARE RESTORE IP
set_real_ip_from 103.21.244.0/22;
set_real_ip_from 103.22.200.0/22;
set_real_ip_from 103.31.4.0/22;
set_real_ip_from 104.16.0.0/12;
set_real_ip_from 108.162.192.0/18;
set_real_ip_from 131.0.72.0/22;
set_real_ip_from 141.101.64.0/18;
set_real_ip_from 162.158.0.0/15;
set_real_ip_from 172.64.0.0/13;
set_real_ip_from 173.245.48.0/20;
set_real_ip_from 188.114.96.0/20;
set_real_ip_from 190.93.240.0/20;
set_real_ip_from 197.234.240.0/22;
set_real_ip_from 198.41.128.0/17;
set_real_ip_from 199.27.128.0/21;
set_real_ip_from 2400:cb00::/32;
set_real_ip_from 2606:4700::/32;
set_real_ip_from 2803:f800::/32;
set_real_ip_from 2405:b500::/32;
set_real_ip_from 2405:8100::/32;
set_real_ip_from 2c0f:f248::/32;
set_real_ip_from 2a06:98c0::/29;

# use any of the following two
real_ip_header CF-Connecting-IP;
#real_ip_header X-Forwarded-For;

 location = /favicon.ico {
            log_not_found off;
            access_log off;
    }

    location / {
    root   /var/www/kasacja-aut.pl;
    error_page 500 502 503 504 404 = /index.html;
        # Wywal boty z Layer-7 damm.
        if ($http_user_agent ~* foo|bar) {
            return 403;
        }
    proxy_cookie_path / "/; secure; HttpOnly";
    }

    location ~* \.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico|woff2|ttf|otf|eot|woff)$ {
            expires max;
            log_not_found off;
    }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

There's an obvious typo you can fix:

```
return 301 https://$kasacja-aut.pl$request_uri;
```

I have no idea what that will do, but it probably won't be good. You probably meant something like:

```
return 301 https://kasacja-aut.pl$request_uri;
```

But if you plan to use HSTS, you should redirect from HTTP to HTTPS to the same hostname first, and then redirect www to non www (or vice versa) in a separate HTTPS `server` block.

```
return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
```

Comment: It didn't help :/. Steal reapats 414 Request-URI Too Large.

Comment: @RyanSlightEdge Did you clear your browser cache?

Comment: Ouch, thanks. Can you help me with 301 redirect? I'm newbe as you can see and I don't want to mess up the structure.